# Div update with jQuery and Yii not works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii

I utilise [responsiveslideshow](http://responsiveslides.com/) lib to show a slideshow of RSS news.
So, I wish to update content of the div each hour to have last news.
This is my **[protected/views/layouts/slideshow.php](http://pastebin.com/r7sYME8h)**
The class *News* simply returns news in a ul list
Finally, this the javascript I call in the view

```
    function responsiveText()
    {
        $('#footer').css('font-size', $('#footer').css('height'));
    }

    // call slideshow lib
    $(function() 
    {       

            // news slideshow
            $("#newsSlider").responsiveSlides(
            {
                    // 3 sec
                    timeout: 5000,
            });

            responsiveText();

            // responsive news 
            $(window).resize(function(){
                    responsiveText();   
            });

    });
```

**The problem** is that after div refresh the view only shows the first news and the scrolina/animation doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this library but something is strange in your code :

```
 responsiveText();

 // responsive news 
 $(window).resize(function(){
      responsiveText();   
 });
```

Are you sur this code is called ? This part is not in your function responsiveSlides() which have a Timeout (here called every 5 seconds).

If you read the documentation of the library you have a "after: function(){}". Maybe you should put your code inside ?

```
$("#newsSlider").responsiveSlides(
{
    // 5 sec
    timeout: 5000,

    after: function(){
        responsiveText();

        // responsive news 
        $(window).resize(function(){
                responsiveText();   
        });
    }
});
```

Never tried it but hope it's helpful.